# Proof that $Z$ is a gcd ring

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Recall the general definition of a gcd in a commutative ring $R$.

For $a \in R$, $\mathcal D(a)$ is the set of elements that divide $a$ and if $S \subset R$, $\mathcal D(S) = \cap_{s \in S} \mathcal D(s)$

We say that $d$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$ and we write $d \in \gcd(a,b)$ whenever we have $ d \in \mathcal D(a,b) \subset \mathcal D(d) $.

I would like to prove that, within the ring $\mathbb Z$ every pair of natural numbers has a gcd, that is, $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N} \quad \gcd(a,b) \neq \emptyset $.
Of course, they all have a gcd for the order in $\mathbb Z$, in which case I'd like to prove that the greatest common divisor for the order *is* a (the) greatest common divisor in the purely algebraic sense.

Once done, it almost goes without saying that the gcd is unique.
Indeed, since $\forall x,y \in \mathbb N \quad (x|y \implies x \leq y)$, $\quad \mathcal D(a,b)$ is bounded by $\min(a,b)$ and has a unique maximal element. If $a$ and $b$ do have a gcd, then, once again by $x|y \implies x \leq y$ the gcd can only be that maximal  element.

Therefore, proving that $a$ and $b$ have a gcd is equivalent to proving that the greatest element of $\mathcal D(a,b)$ (the "usual" greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$) is a gcd of $a$ and $b$, that is, that every element of $\mathcal D(a,b)$ divides its greatest element.

I'm stuck here.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: ‘whenever $d \in \mathcal D(a,b) \subset \mathcal D(d)$’.

Comment: This means $d$ divides $a$ and $b$ and is divisible by every common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That's not what your formula means. Actually it is ill-formed.

Comment: If you do unterstand what I meant, would you mind helping me to reformulate ?

Comment: @Rob Arthan: you meant $\mathcal D(\{a, {\color{red}b}\})\subset \mathcal D(\{d\})$.

Comment: You seem to be lost in your own notation. When you write ${\cal D}(a, b)$, you probably mean ${\cal D}(\{a, b\})$.  Defining $\gcd(a, b)$ to be the set of $d$ such that $d \in {\cal D}(\{a, b\}$ and ${\cal D}(\{a, b\}) \subseteq {\cal D}(\{d\})$ is a very convoluted way of defining greatest common divisors.

Comment: @Bernard: sure! but that just reinforces my point - convoluted notation encourages errors.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. I thought I'd lighten the notation, as we do when we write $f(x,y)$ instead of $f((x,y))$ when $(x,y)$ is an argument of $f$.
We have no trouble writing $(a,b)$ and $(S)$ for ideals generated by subsets or several elements.

Comment: @James The definition is so $\,c\mid a,b,\ldots\!\! \iff\! c\mid \gcd(a,b,\ldots)\ $ i.e they have exactly the same set of *common* divisors $\,c,\,$ that is $\ \cal D(a,b\ldots)\, =\, \cal D(\gcd(a,b\ldots))\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque There is "greatest" for the order on $\mathbb Z$ and "greatest" for the partial order that is divisibility.

Comment: @James My comment refers to the general (divisibility-greatest) definition of gcd.

Comment: @BillDubuque 1st comment : Yes, but $d$ is my $\gcd $, so isn't that what I've written ?
2nd comment : exactly, and in $\mathbb Z$ there is of course a greatest common divisor in the order sense, and I was seeking to prove that that element *is* the $\gcd $ in the divisibility sense.

Comment: @James My point was to show you how to say it more clearly.

Comment: Right, I'll edit that, I can tell that I haven't made it clear. Thx

Comment: I understand well what you are trying to prove (I've [written far more](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/greatest-common-divisor/topusers) on this site about gcds than any other user - including the topic you mention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf Z$ is a P.I.D., hence the ideal $\langle a,b\rangle$ has a generator $d$, and every generator is unique modulo units. The units of $\mathbf Z$  are $\pm 1$, so we can choose the *positive* generator.

By definition, $a, b\in\langle d\rangle$, so $d\mid a, b$.

On the other hand, we can write $d=ua+vb$ for some $u,v\in\mathbf Z$ since $d\in\langle a,b\rangle$. Let $e$ be a common divisor of $a$ and $b$:  we can write $a=a'e$, $b=b'e$, so
$$d=ua'e+vb'e=(ua'+vb()e\in\langle e\rangle ,$$
which means $e$ is a divisor of $d$.

*Note*

This proof is valid for any P.I.D., even if it has no *Euclid's algorithm*.

Comment: Oh yes! It only uses that a non-empty set of natural numbers has a smallest element (of course, this property is also used to prove the existence of a Euclidean division).

Comment: I think I deleted my question by mistake. It was : Can one prove that $\mathbb Z$ is a PID without using that it is Euclidean ?

Comment: It was this question indeed and I didn't delete my comment-answer. In short: if $I$ is a non-zero ideal, it is generated by the smallest  positive integer it contains.

Answer (score 1):

**Euclid's algorithm** for computing the GCD can be turned directly into a proof that the any two naturals $a$ and $b$ have a unique GCD, by long induction on $a+b$:

If $a=b$, then their common value is obviously their GCD.

Otherwise, suppose without loss of generality that $a>b$. Then the common divisors of $a-b$ and $b$ are easily seen to be the same as the common divisors of $a$ and $b$. But the induction hypothesis tells us that $a-b$ and $b$ have a unique GCD.

Comment: Euclid's algorithm isn't required for the existence of gcds.

Comment: @Bernard: I never said it was -- there are GCD rings that are not Euclidean. But it happens to work in $\mathbb Z$.